# Attempting to recreate a network, how to assign edge weight to specific edges?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, sna

So I have been tasked with recreating a specific network as seen here:
[image]

While I have been able to figure out how to play around with the nodes, I am unsure how to assign each edge to a width. I am assuming it should be done similarly to node color/shape that is store as a vector. However how do I know exactly which edge is what?

```
library(sna)

hw2 <- rbind(
  # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 932 1 2 3 4 8 0 2
  c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
  c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
  c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
  c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  )

#Labels
rownames(hw2) <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a32","a11","a12","a13","a14","a18","a20","a22")
colnames(hw2) <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a32","a11","a12","a13","a14","a18","a20","a22")

#Colors
net_col <-  c(rep("steelblue",8),rep("lightcoral",2),rep("steelblue",8))
edge_col <- c(rep("blue4",) )
#Shape
net_size <-c(rep(4,8),rep(50,2),rep(4,8))

#Network
net_hw2 <- network(hw2,matrix.type="adjacency")

#Graph 1 , similar to existing graph
gplot(net_hw2,vertex.col = net_col,usearrows = F,displaylabels = T,label.pos = 5,
      vertex.cex = 3, vertex.sides = net_size)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a width to the edges using the edge.lwd argument to gplot.  To match your target graph,  I will also assign a color using edge.col.   The only tricky part is figuring out which edge is which.   I will just set the edge width and color for *one*
edge. After that, I will let you go through to adjust all the others.

You can get all of the edges using `as.edgelist(net_hw2)`  This gives the edges based on the *number* of the nodes.  You can match the node number to its name using your list 
`rownames(hw2)`.  I will use as an example the edge between a3 and a9. This edge is thicker than most of the others and it is yellow instead of blue. Looking at `rownames(hw2)` we see that a3 is node 3 and a9 is node 9.   Looking through the output of `as.edgelist(net_hw2)`  we see that edges 29 and 51 connect these nodes.

I will make a vector of colors and widths so that the default color is navy and the default width is 1.

```
LWD = rep(1, nrow(as.edgelist(net_hw2)))
COL = rep("navy", nrow(as.edgelist(net_hw2)))
```

Now we can explicitly change the color and width for the edges connecting a3 and a9

```
LWD[29] = 8
COL[29] = "yellow"
LWD[51] = 8
COL[51] = "yellow"
```

Now you can just use that in the plot

```
gplot(net_hw2,vertex.col = net_col,usearrows = F, displaylabels = T,
    label.pos = 5, vertex.cex = 3, vertex.sides = net_size, 
    edge.col=COL, edge.lwd=LWD)
```

[image: graph with adjusted edge color and width]

Now we have a nice wide, yellow edge between a3 and a9. 
You can change the color and width of any other edges in the same way.